# What is the difference between NSObject and AnyObject? When to use the two?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I'm trying to create an array to store Strings or an array of custom class. Am I better off creating a dictionary?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`AnyObject` is Swift's representation of Objective-C's `id` type. It's more general than `NSObject` (i.e. every `NSObject` is an `AnyObject`, but not every `AnyObject` is a `NSObject`).

On the other part of the question - depends on how you intend to use the structure. Using a more particular class for the generic structure (Swift's typed array or dictionary) will allow you to enjoy the benefits of the strong typing, whereas using a more generic type will allow you to be more dynamic. Really it depends on what you intend to use the class for.

Comment: Thanks, Alexander. That cleared things up. I'm going with your suggestion, I will create a typed Dictionary which holds a string and an array of custom class.