# Compilation error in swift3: 'AnyObject' is not a subtype of 'NSObject'

Tags: ios, swift3

I am facing with the following error during compilation based on Swift 3.

```
class DetailViewController: UIViewController {

      @IBOutlet weak var detailDescriptionLabel: UILabel!


      var detailItem: AnyObject? {
        didSet {
            // Update the view.
            self.configureView()
        }
      }

      func configureView() {
        // Update the user interface for the detail item.
        if let detail: AnyObject = self.detailItem {
            if let label = self.detailDescriptionLabel {
                label.text = detail.valueForKey("timeStamp")!.description
            }
        }
      }

      override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        self.configureView()
      }

      override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
      }


    }
```

Error:

> /.../DetailViewController.swift:27:33: 'AnyObject' is not a subtype of
>   'NSObject'

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32272771/what-is-the-difference-between-nsobject-and-anyobject-when-to-use-the-two  AnyObject is more generic than NSObject. You need to use a more specific class to get the behavior of NSObject

Comment: Try changing AnyObject? to Any?

Comment: @EugenDimboiu, It won't help. `Any` is even broader than `AnyObject`. You're suggesting moving into different direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just changed it to this. Then it fixed.

```
label.text = (detail.value(forKey: "timeStamp") as! NSObject).description
```

Comment: You should cast the object to the **actual** type rather than something unspecified like `NSObject`. This is Swift. Don't fight the strong type system.

Answer (score 2):

```
if let detail: [String: AnyObject] = self.detailItem {
        if let label = self.detailDescriptionLabel {
            label.text = detail.valueForKey("timeStamp")!.description
        }
    }
```

And if `detailItem` is for storing JSON objects, you'd better cast it to dictionary at the beginning. As if the variable is cast as `AnyObject`, the compile will keep prompting errors as it simply cant handle it (for your case, `AnyObject` class does not have `valueForKey` function).